# Overleaf recognises my bib file but still fills in the citations as question marks

Tags: bibtex, overleaf

I'm currently working on my thesis and I'm using the template of our university. Whilst filling the `.bib` file with citations and adding them into my text using `\cite{name}` I keep getting errors. I attached some files , if not sufficient please let me know. Thanks in advance

Kind regards

Pieter

```
    \clearpage
%you have to add the bibliography items in mijnbibliografie.bib. Most editors offer a menu for this. Also, in google scholar (settings, advanced) you can turn on @get bibtex citation@, this gives you a text to copy in the bibfile.


\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{biblio}
\vfill
```

Code from my `biblio.bib` file

```
@article{ooijenvrabec,
  title={Does the GDPR enhance consumers’ control over personal data? An analysis from a behavioural perspective},
  author={van Ooijen, Iris and Vrabec, Helena U},
  journal={Journal of consumer policy},
  volume={42},
  number={1},
  pages={91--107},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

Code example of a citation

```
    This is example text to make clear waht i did \cite{ooijenvrabec}.
```

Some errors from the console:

```
Package natbib Warning: Empty `thebibliography' environment on input line 3.
Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.
BibTeX: I didn't find a database entry for "ooijenvrabec"
```

Comment: Please don’t post pictures of code

Comment: yeah i dont know how to post the code otherwise, any suggestions? I'm new to this forum

Comment: cut the code as text and paste it in, then use the `{}` button in the editor to show code.  Also show the log and bibtex logs (`.log` and `.blg`

Comment: "keep getting errors" is not inough information to allow anyone to help, show the exact error fron the log file.

Comment: I found the .log and .blg files, but i dont seem to find an option to upload it in this question, I also provided some code. I dont know if you can much with it though...

Comment: We also don't know anything about your document class or preamble. Do you even cite anything?

Comment: Unrelated: depending on your class `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}` is not a good idea, chances are that it will point to the wrong page. Consider using a package like `tocbibind` instead.

Comment: I'm pretty new to Overleaf & Latex, but that was pretty clear. I'm using the school's template @daleif and that was there already.

Comment: Please copy it at post it here. Please don;t use links to external resources and it might be an idea to make a copy instead and make it as minimal as possible (we don't need to see your assignment, but we need a sample document so we have an idea what you are doing.

Comment: You can not upload files here just copy the error message  as text and add it to your question. Overleaf runs the document multiple times so if \cite didn't work you must have an error

Comment: @DavidCarlisle i edited the post, do I still miss certain thinks in order for people to understand my question?

Comment: so the main error you have is `BibTeX: I didn't find a database entry for "ooijenvrabec"`  but that is unlikely to be the first error. Either bibtex did not find your bib file, or it found it but an error stopped it being rerad. Either way it will have reported the problem in the `.blg` file.

Comment: See the form that I used in my (non)-answer. Anyone can take those two files and produce exactly the image that I show, wiothout having to guess unknown fragments. We can not do that with your post and can not produce the described effect of the citation not appearing.

Comment: Yeah i posted everything that had to do with the bibliography... So i really dont know what else I can provide.

Comment: @Pieter take (a copy of) your full document, remove content from it that you think is not related to the bibliography issue, recompile and check it still fails, delete more content, recompile, etc. At some point either the error will be resolved or the document is fully minimal (i.e., something similar to David's example, but then with your own documentclass). If the error is resolved and you don't understand why, take one step back to reintroduce the error and post the full code at that point here. If the error is caused by the class, then post the code of the class.

Comment: We'll vote now to close as 'needs details', once you have those details (following the procedure I outlined above) then you can edit the question and it will be put in a queue for reopening.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to debug fragments so here is a test document

```
\documentclass{article}



\begin{document}

There has been considerable criticism on the efficacy of the GDPR,
many researchers consider this law does not cover enough ground to
strengthen the data subject’s control conveniently
\cite{ooijenvrabec}.



\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{biblio}


\end{document}
```

with biblio.tex

```
@article{ooijenvrabec,
  title={Does the GDPR enhance consumers’ control over personal data? An analysis from a behavioural perspective},
  author={van Ooijen, Iris and Vrabec, Helena U},
  journal={Journal of consumer policy},
  volume={42},
  number={1},
  pages={91--107},
  year={2019},
  publisher={Springer}
}
```

running pdflatex-bibtex-pdflatex (which is automatic at Overleaf) produces

[image]

So if the citation does not work for you you must have a latex or bibtex error in code not shown, show any error from the log or make an extended example that produces  the failed citation.

Comment: Does indeed seem like it is working, so there should be some mistake somewhere else. I'll take a look at my document again and post it here if I find anything. Thank you for your help and time!